# When is EIP register equal to CR2 in 80X86?

Tags: x86, page-fault

If CPU fetchs a instruction, is it possible that EIP == CR2 ?

I just wonder it, but after many searches it seems that nobody cares about it .

Answer (score 2, accepted):

A page fault sets CR2 to the page-fault linear address, but it keeps its value until the next page fault.

After a page fault has been resolved and the page-fault handler returns to user-space, it will re-run the faulting instruction.  The normal way for that to happen is via an `iret` which sets CS:EIP to the exception-return address,.

If the page fault was on code-fetch, and you have a flat memory model (CS base = 0 so EIP = the linear address), then CR2 = address of the faulting instruction, which is also the exception-return address pushed by the #PF exception.

A confounding factor is that *during* execution of an instruction, EIP is the address of the end of the current instruction.  (Relative jumps and `[rip + rel32]` addressing modes are relative to the end of instructions.)  But
if you think of a logical state *between* instructions, like after `iret` sets a new CS:EIP but before fetch+decode of an instruction there changes EIP again, you could have EIP = CR2 during normal operation, without having to do `mov cr2, eax` which could of course trivially create any condition you want.

Of course this is just the *logical* model of execution, running one instruction at a time, in program order.  Maybe a non-pipelined CPU like 386 could actually have physical states like that, but modern superscalar out-of-order exec CPUs only maintain the illusion of running as if they'd done that.

---

Say you had a memory layout like

```
  0x401234   jmp foo
  ...
  0x402000   foo:  nop         # in an page that's not mapped yet
```

A possible sequence of execution could be:

- CR2= unknown, EIP = 0x401234 `jmp foo`,
- CR2= unknown, EIP = 0x402000 (unmapped page)
- CR2= 0x402000, EIP = top of #PF handler (loaded from IDT entry)
- page fault handler wires a page into the HW page table; assuming it was already in RAM somewhere, or after waiting for I/O or decompressing it from zram
- CR2= 0x402000, EIP = end of #PF handler, `iret`
- CR2= 0x402000, EIP = 0x402000, right *after* that `iret`, before starting to execute the `nop`
- CR2= 0x402000, EIP = 0x402001, during execution of the `nop`, and before execution of whatever comes after.